# How do I run a shell script which runs another script with cron?

Tags: cron

Whenn I run

```
sh /opt/script/cypress.sh
```

Everything works, the script changes directory and executes a command to open another script.

But when I have my crontab like this

```
1 * * * * /opt/script/cypress.sh
```

It doesn't work. I edited the crontab with "crontab -e" and tested if it works with a touch command
The cypress.sh looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "/opt/script" | ./cypress > /opt/script/log;
```

And the cypress file looks like:

```
cd "/opt/Website Testing/"
npx cypress run --record --key *
```

I replaced the record key with "*" for this post

Comment: cron sets only a minimal PATH, so either your first script needs to set the correct PATH before executing the second script, or the second script (and any subsequent scripts) should specify the full pathname to executables in non-standard locations.  The former is more reliable, especially if any non-script executables call other programs in non-standard locations.

Comment: Don't you want `cd "/opt/script" && ./cypress`?

Comment: Provide full path to `npx` in the script and do what @KamilMaciorowski tells you. You might want to drop the `cd`s completely and use only absolute paths.

Comment: I have tried the ``` cd "/opt/script" && ./cypress ``` that doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried to use the fullpath to npx which didn't work either, then I tried `36 * * * * cd "/opt/Website Testing" && /opt/rh/rh-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/npx cypress run --record --key` which also didn't work

Comment: In order to not use `scl enable rh-nodejs10 bash` everytime I open a terminal I edited the .bashrc, does cron also uses this when I edited the crontab with the user with that entry?

Comment: In crontab do not forget correctly set the user. You definitely need to look in your local mail box (may be the mail box of local admin) where you can find the error messages.

Comment: I used `crontab -e` as the user I want it to execute @schweik

Now I tried 
`cd /opt/Website\ Testing/ && /opt/Website\ Testing/node_modules/.bin/cypress run --record --key *` which works in the command line but not in crontab

Comment: @schweik just checked the mail box, it says `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is the following configuration:

crontab:

```
0 4 * * * /opt/script/cypress.sh  > /opt/log
```

cypress.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
. $HOME/.bashrc
cd "/opt/Website Testing/" && "/opt/Website Testing/node_modules/.bin/cypress" run --record --key *
```

Thanks for your help, the ". $HOME/.bashrc" was missing for me.